# Calendar month in property letting (UK)

Tags: rental-property, definition, tenancy-rules

A tenancy agreement gives the end date of the tenancy as being on the 30th of a month, where the month has 31 days. The rent is stated as being amount x per calendar month. Is it right, therefore, that for the final month, only (30/31)*the monthly rental amount is paid, or does the definition calendar month mean 30 days (as other calendar months only have 30 days in? Would be great if someone could clarify this for me!

Answer (score 1):

If you pay rent per calendar month, you pay the same amount each month on the same date. In your case, the 30th.

The rent is calculated by dividing the total for the year by 12, or by multiplying the weekly rent by 52/12 (4.3 recurring).

You don't pay for 31 days in January, 28/29 in February, 31 in March, 30 in April etc.